Laravel 5 Auth and OAuth
I’m returning to an old laravel 5.7 API code base that was once working swimmingly. I want to start updating it to laravel 11 (my first time doing upgrades in laravel, so was planning on using Shift) but I want to see everything working locally first so I can test it as I incrementally upgrade it.
It seems like the Auth facade and the guzzle token generation library are no longer working as expected. I’m getting errors that login credentials are incorrect when they’re not, and the API is getting hung when trying to signup at generating a token using guzzle.
Are these methods no longer supported for Laravel 5.7? Would updating the code base hopefully solve these issues? Or is there some way I can solve these issues while still in Laravel 5.7?

You should be able to run a Laravel 5.7 project locally, as long as your PHP version is compatible (might be difficult since PHP 7.X is EoL and thus harder to install locally, not impossible though), and also assuming you can run composer install to get all of your dependencies. That all being said, Laravel 5.7 is very old, and you might simply be better off upgrading, or rewriting to Laravel 11. You can follow the upgrade guides one-by-one until you hit 11, but that won't be an easy task.
